# Highcharts overlay multiple datetime series

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I want to overlay two datetime x-axis which are not from the same daterange but have the same number of points (point index x from series 1 should be next to point index x from series 2).

I tried to achieve this with two x-axis where one being hidden.

I basically seems to work but the bars only align at certain zoom levels.

Zoomed-In:

[image]

Zoomed-Out:

[image]

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8wahvryx/1) is a jsfiddle with the settings I tried:

```js
"xAxis": [{
  tickInterval: 36e5,
  "type": "datetime",
  "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
    "day": "%H"
  },
  visible: false
}, {
  tickInterval: 36e5,
  "type": "datetime",
  "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
    "day": "%H"

  },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from @pawel fus might work in most cases, unfortunately did not for for me.

I ended up using the exact same values for the x-axis of both series and only set a different name for each value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use categories - that way you will get points axis evenly spaced, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/8wahvryx/2/

```
"xAxis": [{
  "type": "category",
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);
    }
  }
}, {
  "type": "category",
  visible: false
}]
```

And if you don't want to change your data format, you can override keys from array (by default it is `[x, y]`) to support names:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
    keys: ['name', 'y']
  }
},
```

Note: In categorised axis, `point.name` is used as category name below the point. Use `xAxis.labels.formatter` or `xAxis.labels.format` to change timestamps to hours.